# Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException.. that's what happens when i try to run the program

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the number of nodes");
    int nonodes = input.nextInt();
    int[] numNodes = new int[nonodes];
    for (int i = 0; i < numNodes.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter the two connected nodes and the distant between them");
        String node1 = input.next();
        String node2 = input.next();
        double dist = input.nextDouble();
    }


}
}
```

Comment: what input do you provide?

Answer (score 0):

Input mismatch exception usually occurs when you provide an input to your scanner instance with a wrong value.

For example, if you ask for an interger using the scanner.nextInt() and provide a string value instead of an integer value. You would get this type of exception. So please do check input.next() and input.nextInt() lines.